# AngularJs resolving errors caused by circular JSON Structures

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, intellij-idea, circular-dependency

So I'm having issues with the following error:

> chartsuccessfulapploginsController.js:59 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>           at Object.stringify (native)

With this snippet of code, that retrieves data from a chart:

```
 var appjson = '{\"APP_DATA_RETRIEVED\" : \"fail\"}';
 var appPostRequest = $.get(appurl, data, appconfig);
 appPostRequest.done(function(appdata){
     console.log(appdata);
     var date=$scope.final.rows[selectedItem.row].c[0].v;
     appjson = JSON.stringify(appdata);
     console.log(appjson);
     var postResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(appjson);
     var postResponse2=postResponse.Response;
     var post=[];
     console.log(postResponse2.length);
     for(i=0; i<postResponse2.length; i++){
         var data = postResponse2[i];
         var dt = new Date(postResponse2[i]['startTime']);
         var day = (dt.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dt.getDate() + '-' + dt.getFullYear();
         if(day==date){
             post=post.concat(data);
             console.log(data);
         }
     }
     console.log(post);
     $scope.gridOptions8.data=post;
     $scope.failchartvisible=true;
     $scope.successchartvisible=false;
     console.log($scope.gridOptions8.data);
     $scope.$apply()//error originates from here
```

The "appdata" parameter in the done function is a JSON object that always has this structure:

```
{
    "Response": [{
        "challenge": "rp6lssenku72b2ppr4gkjb4q92",
        "startTime": "2016-04-26 10:41:46.0",
        "successfullyCompleted": false,
        "id": 1,
        "username": "bojan1037"
    }, {
        "challenge": "ljtqvmk1mcqqqg5m0op0fljnek",
        "startTime": "2016-04-26 10:49:56.0",
        "successfullyCompleted": false,
        "id": 4,
        "username": "bojan1037"
    }, {
        "challenge": "h062sm69lpkib7t3sk4fuppi1v",
        "startTime": "2016-04-26 14:53:31.0",
        "successfullyCompleted": false,
        "id": 10,
        "username": "bojan1037"
    }],
    "Error": ""
}
```

I understand that it has something to do with json.stringify.  However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix the error, as I can't see how that appdata could have a circular reference.  Can anyone help me figure it out?  Whoever answers correctly will have my eternal gratitude.

Comment: Is the `appdata` exactly like what you provided just before the JSON.stringify? Did you `console.log` it?

Comment: @MMhunter Yep.  exactly the same.

Comment: It looks like the problem is not in your given code since it originates from `$scope.$apply()`. Maybe in some $watch or binding functions i think.

Comment: The problem with that is this whole thing worked before.  The only difference was the JSON was just the array of JSON objects

Comment: it's not really clear where your data is getting mangled here, but what is clear is that you are trying to use jQuery to parse and modify data that you then are using in angular bindings, which is generally unnecessary and error prone.

Comment: Also, how is this question different from the question you posted here two days ago?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820441/angularjs-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json-at-object-stringify

Comment: to me, this feels like a lot of unnecessary work.  for example, why are you using `JSON.Stringify` on the data, only to log it and then run `jQuery.parseJSON` on it?  if it was already an object, what's the point of converting the object to a string and then converting it back into a different object?  that's likely your problem.

Comment: besides which, if you use angular aware functions instead of jQuery, none of this conversion back and forth or calling `$scope.$apply()` would be necessary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the culprit is your variable appjson. Somehow it is creating a circular reference with strigify JSON object. Instead of this:

```
var appjson = '{\"APP_DATA_RETRIEVED\" : \"fail\"}';
```

You can try declaring like this:

```
var appjson = {};
```

And whenever you feel the response is unexpected, you can fill this empty object with desired JSON values later.

Comment: Same result, I'm afraid.

Comment: try this out   appjson = JSON.parse(appdata);

Comment: nope, returns this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: still the issue ? Could you please try this - appjson =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(appdata));

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert variable type to string from json in your code : `appjson = JSON.stringify(appdata);`.

I think you'd better use `$httpProvider` in angularjs.

Check yourself API on this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: I do that for error checking.  Whether or not I use $httpProvider has no relevance to this question.